# TextField and Warning

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField object and take input from the textfield. If length of the input is shorter than 2, I want to give warning sign in the textfield bar.

Is this impossible ?

If it is so, how can I handle that ?

**EDIT:**

I just handled it. I put a label in the textfield and run auto layout. Then, I chose delegate of textfield and make `InputViewController` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. Finally, I use `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

Comment: Check the "Using Overlay Views to Edit Content" of `UITextField` Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) to show the warning sign. For the rest, it's about text length, use the `UITextFieldDelegate` appropriate methods.

Comment: @Goktug What do you mean by `sign in the textfield bar`?

Comment: try to implement textfield right view or left view or  just share your expected design image

Comment: I just handled it. I put a label in the textfield and run auto layout. Then, I chose delegate of textfield and make InputViewController conform to UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Finally, I use `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in your view controller and use `textFieldDidEndEditing` to check text length.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let textFieldText = textField.text {
       print("textFieldText length - \(textFieldText.count)")
       if (textFieldText.count < 2) {
          showWarning(message: "Your message here")
       }
    }
}

func showWarning(message: String?){
   // show warning message using UIAlertController here.
}
```

Comment: are you seen this `sign in the textfield bar`

Comment: may be he need to show on above the textfield top layer, just like IQkeyboardmanager shows

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom class inherited from UIView and pack UITextField(No border style) and Iconic Font UILabel inside it.